# How to store loop iteration results to a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, object

I have two DB tables one that holds license keys (Activations) and other one that has serial number of each license key (LicenseSerialNumbers). Primary key of the LicenseSerialNumbers table is foreign key of licenseID column in the Activations table (LicenseSerialNumbers.ID == Activations.licenseID )

Now I had filtered Activations table result to get only the keys activated against a product serial number because of business requirement. I have this result in a List currentKey

```
var currentKey = context.Activations.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Activations where JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.SerialNumber')=@value", new SqlParameter("@value", activationinfo)).ToList();
```

I created ViewModel for both the Models to combine the table results

```
public class LicenseSerialNumberViewModel
{ 
public List<Activation> Activations { get; set; }
public List<LicenseSerialNumber> LicenseSerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

List Join:

```
var data = new LicenseSerialNumberViewModel();
var result = data.LicenseSerialNumber.Join(data.Activations, l => l.Id, a 
=> a.licenseID, (LId, serial) => new{LId = LId.SerialNumber});
```

I expect to publish values of both the tables in one view. The filtered activations table rows must be compared against the LicenseSerialNumber table/ Class and passed onto the view.

Problem : I am not getting the expected result. I am new to programming I made a progress up to this point and stuck in a place where SqlQuery function can take only primitive type variables. But the result currentkey is a list.

```
var currentKey = context.Activations.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Activations where JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.SerialNumber')=@value", new SqlParameter("@value", activationinfo)).ToList(); var id = currentKey.Select(a => a.LicenseSerialNumberId).ToList(); 

var data = context.LicenseSerialNumbers .SqlQuery("Select * from LicenseSerialNumbers where Id =@value", new SqlParameter("@value", id)).ToList();
```

In the above code the id that I passed to @value parameter is a list. But SqlQuery function takes just primitive variables.

How can I iterate over id values and make the variable data a list? I tried foreach and for loop to iterate over id list, but couldn't get the output out of the loop scope.

```
List<long> temp; 

foreach (var i in id) { 

var a = context.LicenseSerialNumbers.SqlQuery("Select * from LicenseSerialNumbers where Id =@value", new SqlParameter("@value", i)).Single();
temp.Add(a); 
}
```

> Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'temp'

How can I iterate and get each compared result added to list?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I don't get the expected result. I am new to programming I know where the problem is but don't know how to come across.

Comment: Done. edited the question

Comment: The error is self explanatory itself! You are using an unassigned local variable! You need to assign a value to a variable before you want to use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialise the `temp` variable before you want to use it. for example like this:

```
List<long> temp = new List<long>(); //<==== HERE

foreach (var i in id) { 
   //...
   temp.Add(a); 
}
```

Comment: It worked, this is the solution I was looking for.

I didn't initialize the list outside the scope, simple mistake consumed lot of my time. 

Thank you.

Comment: @KannanKG your welcome. Please do not forget to mark it as answer and also UpVote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate every id the error in the second part is that you did not instantiate temp

```
List<long> temp = new List<long>();
```

But if you want to have it in one go and your query in the first part

```
Id = @value
```

will only accept a single value.

Try converting the list of long to a string with comma inside a ()

```
List<long> list = new List<long>() {1,2,3}; //list of ids
string convertedListOfLong = string.Join(", ", list);
```

And changing your sql to

```
string.Format("Select * from LicenseSerialNumbers where Id IN ({0})", convertedListOfLong);
```

Comment: Your solution will work definitely, but implementaion will again lead to second problem I had. How can I export the stitched sting out of the foreach or a for loop?

Comment: if the query inside the foreach will return a long then adding it to temp. changing the sql query to IN ({0}) then just make temp = changed sql query and removing foreach loop.

Comment: It worked, thank you for the answer. But the point is I missed to initialize the list outside the loop scope.

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer helped please mark it thanks :)